# AndroidRuntime(883):at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:179)

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentprovider

I tried out this simple demo code on content-providers but i am getting a readExceptionFromParcel exception.

```
Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, editText.getText().toString());
    Cursor idCursor = getContentResolver().query(lookupUri, null, null, null, null);

    startManagingCursor(idCursor);        

    String wherestmt = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = " + idCursor + " And " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = '" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI + "'";        
    Cursor datacursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,null,wherestmt,null,null);

    int nameIdx = datacursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int phoneIdx = datacursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

    datacursor.moveToFirst();

    list = new ArrayList<String>();

    do{

        String name = datacursor.getString(nameIdx);
        String phone = datacursor.getString(phoneIdx);
        list.add(name + " " + phone);           

    }while(datacursor.moveToNext());

    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Please help me in solving this exception.

Answer (score 0):

you can [attach the source code](http://android.opensourceror.org/2010/01/18/android-source/) to your project and see the ContentproviderNative.java you can see the exception that through from DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(reply) line or use logcat.in most of case it is because of permission. do you add read contact permission to your app?